# CSS3 wildcard selection for hover and active

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to use wildcard selection for `:hover` and `active`

My current css is:

```
a.trigger
```

And I transformed it to:

```
a[id*='trigger-'] {

}
```

I also need the same for `hover` and `active`. Can I do that?

```
a.trigger:hover {
}

a.active.trigger {
}
```

How can I transform that using wildcard?

```
a.active.[id*='trigger-'] {
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by wildcard selection for `:hover` and `:active`. What have you tried?

Comment: you mean like `a[id*='trigger-']:hover`? If so yes [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/YQVrz/). If not, then you might have to clarify your question.

Comment: I already found wildcard. What about active?

Comment: Do you mean adding a class to the selector like `a[id*='trigger-'].active`? Then yes [(another example)](http://jsfiddle.net/YQVrz/1/). You can chain selectors if they belong to the same element. I believe even `a.active[id*='trigger-']` would work. Just remember `.` means class, it isn't a concatenation operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not really clear what you’re asking, but is this the answer?

```
a[id*='trigger-']:hover,
a[id*='trigger-']:active {

}
```